# Prolog programing convert from python code

Tags: python, prolog

Write a procedure map_square(List,Result) that calculates the squared value of each element of List and returns the result in the list Result. For example:

```
?- map_square([2,-3,7],L).
L = [4, 9, 49] ;

no
```

my python code

```py
#map_square() method is defiend
def map_square(List,Result):
    #traversed each vakues of List 
    for i in List:
        #squared each values of List and added in Result list
        Result.append(i*i)
    #returned Result list    
    return Result
    
#main script 
#defiend an empty list
L = []    
#called map_square() fucntion and stored returned list in L
L = map_square([2,-3,7],L)
#printed list L
print(L)
```

Python code with output:
[image: python code]

But I want to convert it into a prolog program
how can I do it please help?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, figuring out a solution to your problem in a procedural language like Python and then trying to translate it into Prolog (decidely, non-procedural) is not the way to learn Prolog.

Here's something to get you started. This predicate will copy one list to another:

```
duplicate( []     , []     ) .  % duplicating an empty list is easy.
duplicate( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- % duplicating a non-empty list is easy, too.
  duplicate(Xs,Ys) .            % - and recurse down on the tails.
```

Then executing `duplicate( [a,b,c] , Ys ).` should yield `Ys = [a,b,c]`.

Note that you will need to apply some transform to each Y before unifying it with the head of the results/`Ys` list.